# I am trying to make my program list blog posts in order by the number of likes each blog has

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently working on a blog website and I want to list out the blogs in ascending order based on the amount of likes each blog has. However, whenever I run my current code, whenever I click "view" for one post, all of the post expand when I  only want one of the post to expand, furthermore, whenever I hit "like" a like is left on all posts rather than just the one I left i like on.

Here is my code in App.js:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Blog from './components/Blog'
import blogService from './services/blogs'
import loginService from './services/login'
import BlogForm from './components/BlogForm'
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm'
import Togglable from './components/Toggable'

const App = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([])
  const [user, setUser] = useState('')
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    blogService.getAll().then(blogs =>
      setBlogs( blogs )
    )  
  }, [errorMessage])

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('user')
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
      setUser(user)
      blogService.setToken(user.token)
    }
  }, [])

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const user = await loginService.login({
        username, password
      })

      window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))

      blogService.setToken(user.token)
      setUser(user)
      setUsername('')
      setPassword('')
    } catch (exception) {
      setErrorMessage('Wrong credentials')
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMessage(null)
      }, 5000)
    }
  }

  const handleLogout = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.localStorage.clear()
    setUser('')
  }

    if (user === '') { 
      return (
        <Togglable buttonLabel='login'>
              <LoginForm
              username={username}
              password={password}
              handleUsernameChange={({ target }) => setUsername(target.value)}
              handlePasswordChange={({ target }) => setPassword(target.value)}
              handleSubmit={handleLogin}
              errorMessage={errorMessage}
            />
        </Togglable>
      )} else {
          return (
            <div>
                <h2>blogs</h2>
                <h3>{errorMessage}</h3>
                <nobr>{user.name} logged in</nobr> <button onClick={handleLogout}>logout</button>
                <h2>create new</h2>
                <Togglable buttonLabel='create new'>
                  <BlogForm errorMessage={errorMessage} setErrorMessage={setErrorMessage} />
                </Togglable>
                  <Blog blogs={blogs} setErrorMessage={setErrorMessage}/>
                </div>
              )
        }
}

export default App
```

Finally, here is my code that deals specifically with each blog:

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react"
import blogService from '../services/blogs'
const baseUrl = '/api/blogs'

const Blog = ({blogs, setErrorMessage}) => {
  const [checker, setChecker] = useState(false)
  const [blogLikes, setBlogLikes] = useState(0)
  const buttonText = checker  ? 'hide' : 'view'

  const blogStyle = {
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingLeft: 2,
    border: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 5
  }

  return (
    <>
  {blogs.map(blog => {
    return (
      <>
  {buttonText === "view" ?   
  <div style={blogStyle}>
    {blog.title} {blog.author} <button onClick={() => setChecker(!checker)}>{buttonText}</button>
  </div>
  : <div style={blogStyle}>
      {blog?.title} {blog.author} <button onClick={() => setChecker(!checker)}>{buttonText}</button>
      <p>{blog.url}</p>
      likes {blogLikes} <button onClick={(e, blog) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setBlogLikes(blogLikes + 1)
        blogService.update(blog?.id, {
          user: blog.user?.id,
          likes: blogLikes,
          author: blog.author,
          title: blog.title,
          url: blog.url})
        setErrorMessage(`You liked ${blog.author}s post`)
      }}>like</button>
      <p>{blog.user?.username}</p>
    </div>
    }</>)})}
    </>
  )
}
export default Blog
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you did here is you created `Blog.js`(or whatever name you gave to the source file), you are treating it as an individual blog, and expecting 'blogLikes` to work for an individual blog.

What structure needs to be.
[image: list-item]

---

Create separate components for list and item and include list component into the app.
The quick fix will be,

**App.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import BlogList from './components/Blog'
import blogService from './services/blogs'
import loginService from './services/login'
import BlogForm from './components/BlogForm'
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm'
import Togglable from './components/Toggable'

const App = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([])
  const [user, setUser] = useState('')
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    blogService.getAll().then(blogs =>
      setBlogs( blogs )
    )  
  }, [errorMessage])

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('user')
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
      setUser(user)
      blogService.setToken(user.token)
    }
  }, [])

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const user = await loginService.login({
        username, password
      })

      window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))

      blogService.setToken(user.token)
      setUser(user)
      setUsername('')
      setPassword('')
    } catch (exception) {
      setErrorMessage('Wrong credentials')
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMessage(null)
      }, 5000)
    }
  }

  const handleLogout = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.localStorage.clear()
    setUser('')
  }

    if (user === '') { 
      return (
        <Togglable buttonLabel='login'>
              <LoginForm
              username={username}
              password={password}
              handleUsernameChange={({ target }) => setUsername(target.value)}
              handlePasswordChange={({ target }) => setPassword(target.value)}
              handleSubmit={handleLogin}
              errorMessage={errorMessage}
            />
        </Togglable>
      )} else {
          return (
            <div>
                <h2>blogs</h2>
                <h3>{errorMessage}</h3>
                <nobr>{user.name} logged in</nobr> <button onClick={handleLogout}>logout</button>
                <h2>create new</h2>
                <Togglable buttonLabel='create new'>
                  <BlogForm errorMessage={errorMessage} setErrorMessage={setErrorMessage} />
                </Togglable>
                  <BlogList blogs={blogs} setErrorMessage={setErrorMessage}/>
                </div>
              )
        }
}

export default App
```

**BlogList.js**

To sort blogs by likes you apply `Array.sort()` before mapping.

```
import Blog from './Blog';

const BlogList = ({blogs, setErrorMessage}) => {
    return (
        <>
        {
            blogs.sort((a, b)=> a.likes > b.likes ? 1 : -1 ).map((blog, i) => <Blog key={i} blog={blog} setErrorMessage={setErrorMessage} />
        }
        </>
    )
}
export default BlogList;
```

**Blog.js**

```
import blogService from '../services/blogs';
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

const Blog = ({blog, setErrorMessage}) => {
    const [checker, setChecker] = useState(false)
    const [blogLikes, setBlogLikes] = useState(blog.likes)
    const buttonText = checker  ? 'hide' : 'view'
    
    const blogStyle = {
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingLeft: 2,
        border: 'solid',
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 5
    }
    
    return (
        <>
        {buttonText === "view" ?
        <div style={blogStyle}>
        {blog.title} {blog.author} <button onClick={() => setChecker(!checker)}>{buttonText}</button>
        </div>
        : <div style={blogStyle}>
        {blog?.title} {blog.author} <button onClick={() => setChecker(!checker)}>{buttonText}</button>
        <p>{blog.url}</p>
        likes {blogLikes} <button onClick={(e, blog) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            setBlogLikes(blogLikes + 1)
            blogService.update(blog?.id, {
                user: blog.user?.id,
                likes: blogLikes,
                author: blog.author,
                title: blog.title,
                url: blog.url})
                setErrorMessage(`You liked ${blog.author}s post`)
            }}>like</button>
            <p>{blog.user?.username}</p>
            </div>
        }
        </>
    )
}
export default Blog
```

Since you have a separate state for likes here in the Blog component its action or data won't affect other blog components.

---

[update]
If you are familiar with `context` then try it, for the beginner you move like action to `App.js` and pass it as a prop just like you did for `setErrorMessage`. Also, add empty `useEffect` with `blogs` dependency in `App.js` so its change will cause re-render.

Comment: I am now getting an error stating that "setErrorMessage" is not a function in **Blog.js**

Comment: Nvm, fixed the above error, however, how would i now sort the blogs in order from highest liked blog to least liked blog? That was what I was originally trying to do... thanks!

Comment: With every new like, will this update the page to show the newest highest liked blog?

Comment: how would u work on it? Im kind of lost on how to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort the blogs based on the likes count and if you want to update it for every like, below are the possible ways i can think:

1. if you are working on POC, then on each hit of like you can update (update function should be passed from app to blog component and called from blog component when like button is clicked) the blogs list and pass it as prop to the Blog list component from the parent / App component
2. For full app(like Twitter / FB) kind of implementation you need to either use `websocket` API or some kind of `publish/subscribe` mechanism or `calling rest api at fixed intervals` ...etc